# Windows Terminal-PowerShell some glyph icons are not rendering when using Cascadia code PL

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal, powerline

I am using windows terminal - PowerShell core 7.

Cascadia code version - 2102.25
font face: cascadia code PL

theme: Paradox, The glyph before 3.8.3 is not rendering.
[image]

theme: Aliens, The glyph before ~2 is not rendering.
[image]

theme: AgnosterPlus, The many glyphs are not rendering.
[image]

Many other themes also, some glyphs are not rendering.

Comment: Glyphs not rendering usually means that they don't exist in the font being used. Try locating a fixed-pitch font that has the glyphs in question, and set Terminal to use that font instead of whatever font it is currently set for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have finally found a solution. The new Cascadia code PL does not support many glyphs like home, python, etc. The solution is to use Cascadia code nerd fonts patched.

[Cascadia code nerd font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v3.1.1/CascadiaCode.zip)

To see more nerd fonts refer
[Nerd Fonts](https://www.nerdfonts.com/)

Comment: Wondering why this font was last updated in 2019 and the microsoft cascadia code keeps being updated constantly. What would we miss by using this 2019 version?

Comment: The 2019 version has some misaligned symbols. For example, the arrow symbols stoop down a little bit and is misaligned with the dash symbol. There could be more but I use the arrow in my custom prompt so that's the extend of my knowledge. Tested in Windows Terminal and Alacritty.